# Get enumeration of lists with specific content type

Tags: list, content-type

I need to present the user with a drop down of lists that contain a specific Content Type. The selected drop down item will be used within a workflow. The idea is similar to the existing functionality when associating a workflow when you select a list to hold the Tasks and a list to hold the History.

The code I came up with is as follows but it does not seem to work.

```
private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<Guid, string> GetTechnicalRoutingContentTypeUsage() {
  var contentType = this.Web.Site.RootWeb.AvailableContentTypes[new SPContentTypeId("0x010089E3DFDB8C9D4B3FBB980447E313CE27")];
  if (contentType == null) { return null; }

  var lists = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Guid, string>();

  var usages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(contentType);

  foreach (var usage in usages) {
    if (usage.IsUrlToList) {
      var list = this.Web.GetListFromUrl(usage.Url);

      lists.Add(list.ID, list.Title);
    }
  }

  return lists;
}
```

*Note that `this` refers to an instance of `LayoutsPageBase` since the method is being run within my workflow association form.*

The problem is with the `GetListFromUrl` method. It returns the very unhelpful exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Should I be collecting this information in a different manner? I know I can get a list of all the websites, then traverse through the lists while checking the ContentTypes property for each one but that seem like the long way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPContentTypeUsage.Url returns server relative Url in case of usage in a list. Instead of SPWeb.GetListFromUrl(usage.Url) use

```
var list = this.Web.GetList(usage.Url);
```

Or

```
var list = this.Web.GetList(this.Web.Url + usage.Url);
```

Comment: So even though I am only dealing with a top level site/web, I need to be using Web.GetList() instead of Web.GetListFromUrl()?

Comment: GetListFromUrl() expects url to a webpart page (for example url to a view, like http://...../AllItems.aspx) while GetList() expect Url to the list, like "/Lists/ListName". usage.Url returns Url to the list, not to a webpart page. If you still have problems try with this.Web.Site.RootWeb.GetList(usage.Url).